# How to deal with delegation of UNUserNotificationCenter and FIRMessaging w/ Firebase in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging, remote-notifications

I'm trying to implement push notifications into my application with Firebase, however when following their documentation I have to add the following line of code:

```
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: {_, _ in})

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }
```

Upon adding this code, the application will not compile, and it will throw an error at me letting me know that I

> cannot assign value of type `AppDelegate` to type
>   `FirMessagingDelegate`

and that I

> cannot assign value of type AppDelegate to type
>   UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate.

So naturally, I add the `FIRMessagingDelegate` and `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to my application, however the `FIRMessagingDelegate` does not allow the application to compile saying that

> type AppDelegate does not conform to protocol 'FirMessagingDelegate'.

Any ideas? I haven't managed to find any other situations in which others have encountered this error, and in Google's documentation, these two delegates aren't even added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right track, 1 more thing to do is making your AppDelegate class conform to the 'FirMessagingDelegate' protocol, by implementing the `applicationReceivedRemoteMessage` function somewhere is your AppDelegate class as it is required by the 'FirMessagingDelegate' protocol described here [Firebase Doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasemessaging/api/reference/Protocols/FIRMessagingDelegate)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't find that... Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me too!! Thanks, btw it is also given in the Firebase sample code  [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/messaging)

Comment: Looking how they did ApplDelegate also helps: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/539d636db0afbcb1d285a4e49adf2d1725f16918/messaging/MessagingExampleSwift/AppDelegate.swift#L40-L55